# Particles Emit from Collection instead of particle emitter

Tags: particles

Here's a short video describing the problem: https://youtu.be/qrjjohJGhfg

I have set up a particle system where a face emits a couple of particles (this is actually a laser gun.)

As long as I have it set to render as an object, things work fine.  Particle shoots out from the face, and is rendered as my laser object.

But, because I'm rendering in Eevee, I also parented some area lights to the laser so that it would actually eminate light onto surrounding geometry (emission node currently doesn't do this in Eevee.)

So I created a new collection with the laser and its lamps, and place it into the particle system just as I did with the laser object, except now I choose "whole collection."

The odd thing is that now the particles are being emitted directly from the collection location instead of the particle emitter.  Bug, or feature?  Thanks!

Comment: Please Move your objects closer to the World origin for comparison.

Comment: Please [Exclude from View Layer ]. Try turning off the collection in the outliner and moving your collection to the world origin. This may allow an unblocked view and a visible render. –

Answer (score 0):

As commented by atomicbezierslinger, this was a problem with the origin of the collection, when it is created, being the center of the scene.  This is as opposed to the object being used with its local origin when being emitted as a particle.

Moving the collection to the world origin emits it correctly.  This does, however, lead to the problem of having your original object right in the middle of the scene and causing you to move everything else away from that point in order to not see the original object.